# How to set a filename for downloading csv file with react-table?

Tags: reactjs, export-to-csv, react-table

I am using `react-table v7`, `useExportData` and `papaparse` to download a .csv from a table referencing to this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gargroh/react-table-plugins/tree/master/examples/export-data?file=/src/App.js), so far it downloaded successfully but I can't find a way to name a file to download. My code is following

```
  function getExportFileBlob({ columns, data, fileType, fileName }) {

    if (fileType === "csv") {
      // CSV example
      const headerNames = columns.map((col) => col.exportValue);
      const csvString = Papa.unparse({ fields: headerNames, data });

      return new Blob([csvString], { type: "text/csv" });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the getExportFileName function defined in the [docs](https://github.com/gargroh/react-table-plugins/blob/master/docs/useExportData.md) and overwrite the default all-data.fileType or data.fileType name.
by returning a name for your exported data. Check out the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-sound-w4j1jm?file=/src/App.js)!
Hope this helps.

`

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but for those seeking for an answer, according to [docs](https://github.com/gargroh/react-table-plugins/blob/master/docs/useExportData.md),

```
getExportFileName: Function({ fileType, all }) => string
```

is the function you need to override the default file name.
I believe you can access it from main `useTable` where you are passing this plugin:

```js
      const {
        ....
        exportData,
      } = useTable(
        {
          getExportFileName: ({ all }) => {
            return `${all ? 'exported-all' : 'current-view-only'}` // <--- there
          },
        },
        useExportData
      )
```

check it out, hope this helps!